# How to get predictions vector from Theano stacked autoencoder

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

I'm trying to modify Stacked Autoencoder for classification from Theano [deep learning tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/deeplearning.pdf), chapter 8. The code of autoencoder I'm dealing with is available [here](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/SdA.py).

My dataset consists of 4 arrays: test_set_x, test_set_y, valid_set_x, valid_set_y. The names are self-explained.

This is how the trained autoencoder is checked on validation set:

```
valid_score = the.function([], sda.errors,
                 givens={
                    sda.x: valid_set_x,
                    sda.y: valid_set_y},
                 name='valid_test')

print valid_score()
```

This code prints out "0.87" on my dataset, so it does work.

Expressing it more verbose

```
valid_score = the.function([], T.mean(T.neq(sda.logLayer.y_pred, sda.y)),
                 givens={
                    sda.x: valid_set_x,
                    sda.y: valid_set_y},
                 name='valid_test')
```

still gives correct answer 87%.

But whenever I'm trying to get directly the real class prediction vector, I get some very wrong result: all elements of result vector are equal to 4 (one on my classes).

My try looks like this:

```
predict = the.function([], sda.logLayer.y_pred,
                   givens={sda.x: valid_set_x})
print predict()
```

This prints out "[4, 4, 4, ....., 4, 4]". Comparing this result with valid_set_y vector gives about 12% correctness, not even nearly 87%.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Please help me if you've ever had a deal with theano autoencoders and/or the mentioned tutorial.

Thank you.

Comment: How come you are only using the logistic layer ? the input should first go through the sigmoid layers - right ? then finally through the logistic layer.

Answer (score 2):

The `valid_score` output is the **error** rate on the validation set. A validation score of `87%` means that you managed to classify correctly only ~12% of your validation examples. This result seems to be consistet with an "all 4" prediction rule.